# Element changing to "element inside" on mouse move listener

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, element, onmousemove

so this is my question. I have two divs one inside of another and i set an eventListener of type mousemove to the parent div. The problem is that when i move the mouse on the child div the element target also changes. How can i make to the element of the eventListener just be the parent element ?

For example:

```
<div id="parent" onmousemove="handleShowElement">
   <div id="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

So now i'm going to create a function the will be triggered when the mouse move on the parent div

```
function handleShowElement(e){

console.log(e.target)

}
```

So the console will show me the "parent" as normal, but as soon as i move the mouse on the div "child" the element changes to the div "child" and shows it on the console.

Is there anyway where i can move the mouse and the element never changes ? Make a way to the element be always the "parent" div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `Event.preventDefault()` may work, but to be more specific, what you really need is **not** to allow the event to propagate i.e. also apply for the parent **div**.
You can precisely do that by using [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
function handleShowElement(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    // access the target from which the event got triggered
    let source = e.currentTarget;
    
    // do some processing
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not working, the div "child" keeps showing on console

Comment: @DenisCoder Please try `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.

Comment: Thank you ! that works !!! Can you make this as an answer for people that comes reach your answer ? Then i will close this question

Comment: @DenisCoder Glad it helped. This is already an answer, I have made it more complete now. You may want to accept this as your accepted solution ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Event.preventDefault()`

Refrence at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

For your case the code is as follows:

```js
function handleShowElement(e){

   e.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not working, the div "child" keeps showing on console